# Deleting elements from matrix in C

Tags: arrays, c, matrix

How can I delete the even elements from main and secondary diagonal of a square matrix and odd elements only from main diagonal?

The problem that I have with this is that I don't know how to move the elements of a matrix and keep the original order to get a matrix without these elements.

I am a beginner, and I hope you could help. Additionally, new matrix cannot be used.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int m[50][50], k[50][50], i, j, n, m, t=0;
  m = n; //n is the size of the matrix

  for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
    for (j=0; j<n; j++) {
      scanf("%d", &m[i][j]);
    }
  }

  for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
    for (j=0; j<n; j++) {
      if (i == j) {
        if (m[i][j] % 2 == 0 || (m[i][j] % 2 == 1))
          m[i][j] = m[i][j - 1];
      }
    }
  }

  n--;

  for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
    for (j=0; j<n; j++) {
      if (i + j + 1 == n) {
        if (m[i][j] % 2 == 0)
          t=1
        m[i][j] =m [i][j - 1];
      }
    }
  }

  if (t == 1) n--;
          
  for (i=0; i<m; i++) {
    for (j=0; j<n; j++) {
      printf("%d", m[i][j]);
    }
  }
}
```

Example: 1 2 3 4 5  (input) This is an example of what program should do:

```
6 7 8 9 1
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 1
1 2 3 4 5
                    
2  3  4  5    (output)
6  8  9  1    
1  2  4  5    
6  7  8  1    
1  2  3  4
```

Comment: First thing to do: indent your code properly

Comment: Instead of moving stuff, just make a *new* matrix as the *output* of the current matrix.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Using new matrix is not alllowed

Comment: You can't **delete** elements of a matrix in C.  All you can do is set the elements to different values.

Comment: @AndrewHenle If we delete a certain element, it should become the element next to it. We can do this with arrays, why can't we do something like this with matrices?

Comment: No, you can't. You can't delete `array[4]` and have it become what used to be `array[5]`.  All you can do is set the ***value*** of `array[4]` to what's in `array[5]`.  Anyone telling you to actually ***delete*** the actual members of an array doesn't understand C at all.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this condition will always be true

```
if(m[i][j]%2==0 || (m[i][j]%2==1))
```

so you can omit it.

Then you used `m[i][j]=m[i][j-1]` for both the main diagonal and the secondary one, that is nonsense.

If you run this program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        
        for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
            
            printf("%d|%d ", i, j);
        }
        puts("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You will see that in the main diagonal `i` and `j` have always the same value, while in the secondary one their sum is constant.

Notice that since you "delete" only few elements from the secondary diagonal, your matrix will end up having rows of variable length. To print only the elements of the final matrix you should keep track of the length of each row.
Or alternatively, you could choose a sentinel value (maybe 0 since in your example you don't have it in the input matrix) and initialize the whole matrix with that value, so when printing the rows you stop when you find the sentinel value, without needing to keep track of rows' length.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example only showing how to remove the main diagonal. You could start from there to handle you exact requirements :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void printMatrix(int mat[50][50], int n, int m) {
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<m;j++){
            printf("%d ", mat[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    int mat[50][50], i,j;
    int n = 6;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
        for(j=0;j<n;j++) mat1[i][j] = rand() % 10;
    }
    printMatrix(mat, n, n);
    printf("=========\n");

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(j=i+1; j<n; j++) mat[i][j-1] = mat[i][j];
    }
    printMatrix(mat, n, n-1);
    return 0;
}
```

Output :

```
3 6 7 5 3 5 
6 2 9 1 2 7 
0 9 3 6 0 6 
2 6 1 8 7 9 
2 0 2 3 7 5 
9 2 2 8 9 7 
=========
6 7 5 3 5 
6 9 1 2 7 
0 9 6 0 6 
2 6 1 7 9 
2 0 2 3 5 
9 2 2 8 9
```

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean exactly : could you be more specific ?

Comment: And since someone wrongly flagged the comment I need to recall *what* I said: `for(j=0;j<n;j++){ if (i == j)` ... the loop is completely useless. You loop `j` from `0` to `n-1` to find the number that equals to `i`, well that number **is** `i`.

Comment: How stupid, I completely missed that ! Thanks for the clarification !